# Entropy of the key

Tags: cryptanalysis, randomness, one-time-pad

> Suppose a $1000$-bit key used in the one-time pad is not randomly and uniformly generated.
>
> 1. Suppose that the values of the first $5$ bits are $0$, and the other $995$ bits are randomly generated and uniformly distributed (each bit with value $0$ and $1$ with probability  $0.5$), what is the entropy of the key?
> 2. Suppose that each bit of the key is randomly generated but with value $0$ with probability $0.54$. What is the entropy of the key?

I have no idea how to start the two questions above. For part 1, I use the entropy formula $$-\sum_{x \in X}{P(x) \log_2 P(x)}$$ but I don't know what should I let $X$ be.
Can anyone guide me?

EDIT: Proof of Additivity of Shannon Entropy

Aim: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then $H(X,Y) = H(X)+H(Y)$

Proof: Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, we have
$$P(X=x)=\sum_{y \in Y}{P(X=x,Y=y)}$$
$$P(Y=y)=\sum_{x \in X}{P(X=x,Y=y)}$$

Question: Do the equations above require the independence of $X$ and $Y$? If they are not independent, are the equations still true?

Comment: It's not a one-time pad if the key is not randomly and uniformly generated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since bits are independently generated, the entropy of the key is the sum over the entropy of the individual bits. The following calculations use the chance $P(x)$ of a zero or one bit.

1. The first 5 bits are constant and thus have 0 entropy.

   The others are unbiased and have 1 bit of entropy each. $P(0)=P(1)=0.5$.

   $-2\cdot(0.5 \cdot \log_2(0.5))= -log_2(0.5) = -log_2(2^{-1}) = 1$

   for a total of 995 bits of entropy.
2. For each bit, use the formula with $P(0)=0.54$ and $P(1)=0.46$

   $-\sum_{x \in X}{P(x)\cdot \log_2(P(x))} = -(0.54 \cdot \log_2(0.54) + 0.46 \cdot \log_2(0.46)) \approx 0.9954$

   for a total of 995.4 bits of entropy.

Comment: For part $(1)$, if I want to use the formula, what should be my $P(x)$?

Comment: For the first 5 bits it's $P(0)=1$ and $P(1)=0$, for the other 995 bits it's $P(0)=0.5$ and $P(1)=0.5$.

Comment: Actually for part$(b)$, I am required to prove that entropy of the key is the sum of the entropy of individual key.

Comment: For part $(b)$, shouldn't we need to multiple $0.9954$ with $1000$ since the length of the key is $1000$?

Comment: 1) Just search for a proof for additivity of Shannon entropy. This is such a basic property that you should find plenty. 2) 0.9954 is the entropy per bit. The entropy of the whole is obviously 1000 times that value.

Comment: Since the first 5 bits are fixed their entropy is 0
For the remaining 995 bits you first calculate the entropy for ONE bit:
P(0)=0.54 and P(1)=0.46 −∑x∈XP(x)⋅log2(P(x))=
−(0.54⋅log2⁡(0.54)+0.46⋅log2⁡(0.46))≈0.9954 bits of entropy PER bit The entropy for the 995 bits = 995⋅0.9954 = 990.423 bits of entropy (it's obvious the entropy for the 995 bits must be < 995)

Comment: @RAW You misread the question. In scenario 1, there are 995 uniformly random bits, so the entropy is exactly 995 bits. In scenario 2 all 1000 bits are random but biased. There is no scenario where there are 995 biased bits.